# Convert Curl command to PHP Guzzle for multiple file uploads

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I wanted to convert following Curl command line to php/curl but for many reasons my customer wants guzzle in PHP.

curl -X POST "https://uploadexample.net/api/upload" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer: 928292992qwg" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "front_photo=@photo-1-214x300.jpg;type=image/jpeg" -F "back_photo=@photo-2-214x300.jpg;type=image/jpeg"

I have never used guzzle but I tried to manually convert above Curl to this guzzle routine. I get 500 server error.  Am I converting correctly?
I was trying to stay as close to original curl as possible.

```
$headers = [
    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    "Authorization" => "Bearer 928292992qwg"
];   
$client = new Client([
     Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://exampleuploadrx.net',
]);
  
$response = $client->request('POST', '/api/upload',  [  
 'json' => [
    'front_photo' => new CURLFile('photo-1-214x300.jpg;type=image/jpeg'),
    'back_photo' => new CURLFile('photo-2-214x300.jpg;type=image/jpeg'),
    ],
                'headers' => $headers,
             
    ]
    );
```

Comment: The cURL command is not sending JSON, so why are you trying to do that with your guzzle request? You got a run-of-the-mill HTTP file upload here. https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking into it now.